# run a yarn application on AMAZON EMR

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I want run yahoo`s project storm-on-yarn on AMAZON EMR. On the EMR, supervisor local directory can not create. I think maybe connect problem or no permission.
Could you give me some suggestion? thank you for your help.

> 2017-03-01 11:38:02 supervisor [ERROR] Error on initialization of
>   server mk-supervisor java.io.IOException: Unable to create directory
>   /mnt/yarn,/mnt1/yarn/usercache/yarn/appcache/application_1488367739843_0002/container_1488367739843_0002_01_000006/storm/storm-1.0.1/storm-local/supervisor   at
>   org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceMkdir(FileUtils.java:2384)
>   ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]     at
>   org.apache.storm.config$supervisor_local_dir.invoke(config.clj:172)
>   ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]     at
>   org.apache.storm.config$supervisor_isupervisor_dir.invoke(config.clj:177)
>   ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]     at
>   org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor$fn__9230$exec_fn__2461__auto____9231.invoke(supervisor.clj:781)
>   ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]     at
>   clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:160) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
>     at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]    at
>   clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:630) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]    at
>   org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor$fn__9230$mk_supervisor__9275.doInvoke(supervisor.clj:779)
>   [storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]  at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]     at
>   org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor$_launch.invoke(supervisor.clj:1216)
>   [storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]  at
>   org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor$_main.invoke(supervisor.clj:1249)
>   [storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]  at
>   clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]    at
>   clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]  at
>   org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.main(Unknown Source)
>   [storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]

Answer (score -1):

1. Passwordless SSH is already the default, and you would have to specifically enable SSH login with a password (and it would not be a good idea to do so because it is less secure than using a keypair, which I assume is what you mean by "ssh login without password").

When you create an EMR cluster, you may optionally specify the name of an SSH key to use (after having already either uploaded the public key or having used the AWS Console/CLI to create the keypair for you), then you may SSH to the EMR cluster's master instance with the private key (usually a .pem file).

For more information, see these pages:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-connect-master-node-ssh.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html

2. It is difficult to tell what the problem is because you have not provided much information, but it sounds like you may have SSH'd to the cluster as 'ec2-user'. When using EMR, you should SSH to the cluster as the 'hadoop' user instead. If that does not solve your problem, please update the question with more details about what you are doing.

Comment: I have updated my question. maybe you can give me some suggestion.thank you for your help.

Comment: With what user are you running this application? If you don't know, with what command did you SSH to the cluster? Also, what command are you using to run the application. Lastly, Storm on YARN isn't something that is officially supported on EMR, so what instructions did you follow to install it?

Comment: I have running this application with default user,hadoop. And I using SSH to connect the master node.  On EMR, I deploy this application like on the local hadoop cluster. I deploy the application following the yahoo provide document. I put the storm project into HDFS, and install storm-yarn and storm on master node. The nimbus of storm can start in yarn container, but the supervisor can not start. Error on initialization of yarn container.